# Cleanest way to do something like "Sentences.each.each" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, coding-style, each

Let's say I have an array of sentences:

```
a = ["I love pie", "I love you more and more each day", "every day is a good day"]
```

I want to test each word in the sentence. Because ruby is so awesome I thought a.each.each might work but it doesn't. Is there a clean way to this without having to nest an each inside of an each?

Comment: Worth noting that there's no String#each, so "I love pie".each is a `NoMethodError`. You'd need `"I love pie".split.each`, even without the wrapping array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.each { |sentence| sentence.split.each { |word| # do something with the word } }
```

or a slightly longer format if:

```
a.each do |sentence|
  sentence.split.each do |word|
    # do something
    # do something
    # do something
  end
end
```

Comment: well if you need a one liner, the first one could work. but if you need to do a bunch of stuff with each `word`, then you may want to use multi-line `do...end` blocks instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid nesting (at least visually), you can use:

```
a.map(&:split).flatten.each{ |word| # do something }
```